# Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

```
 function Student_model()
     {

         parent::Model();
     }

 function insert_data($name,$roll,$department,$semester)
         {

         $qry="INSERT INTO data (id,name,roll,department,semeseter) values ('',?,?,?,?)";
         $this->db->query($qry, array($name,$roll,$department,$semester));


         }
}
```

Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

`INSERT INTO data (id,name,roll,department,semeseter) values ('1','adsfas','117437','4th','3rd')`

need some help here.

Comment: Please post up the DDL for the table.

Comment: Please provide the table structure for the `data` table.

Comment: Should that be `semester` instead of `semeseter` ?

Answer (score 10):

The question is old, but i'll add something since no answers has been marked valid.

The error message states the field "name",  so let's ignore misspelling "semeseter" for now.

If the column "name" exists and you got an error message suggesting it doesn't, 
there is likely to be a "trigger before insert" set for this table that references "name" instead of " new.name " somewhere in the trigger body.

I hope this helps people with similar issues.

Comment: This solved my issue. (the "trigger before insert" solution). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest checking the list of columns for the column in question.  It appears that the column you 
are trying to find does not exist.

You might check `"semeseter"` to ensure that this is not a typo of the English word `semester`.

This is likely your issue.